# Automapping collection convention

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

ok, I have difficult time with automapping collections using fluent nhibernate. This time I tried to apply a collection convention which simply says to use camelCaseField with underscore. Well I got the convention loaded and I hit the breakpoint in the method below FNH still produces strange mapping. What I am doing wrong?

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    private IList<Child> _testCollection;
    public virtual IList<Child> TestCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _testCollection;
        }
    }
}
public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionAccessConvention : ICollectionConvention
{
    public void Apply( ICollectionInstance instance )
    {
        instance.Access.CamelCaseField( CamelCasePrefix.Underscore );
    }
}

<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true" name="Test.Parent, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Parent`">
<id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <column name="Id" />
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<bag access="nosetter.camelcase" name="TestCollection" mutable="true">
  <key>
    <column name="Parent_id" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Test.Child, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</bag>
```

EDIT: @Bary: the strange thing is  access="nosetter.camelcase". I think it should be access="field.camelcase-underscore". Any suggestions?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I figure it out.

Conventions work little bit strange but over time I think I will fully realize it. When you want to apply a convention about certain property or anything it will be applied only if it is not configured/set/defined already. So, when fluent compiles the mappings it automatically sets the readonly properties to access="nosetter.camelcase". Fortunately there is a way to fix this.

The solution:

You have to define your own automapping configuration by extend ***DefaultAutomappingConfiguration*** class and then override the method ***public virtual Access GetAccessStrategyForReadOnlyProperty(Member member)*** OR just implement the ***IAutomappingConfiguration*** interface. After you are done you can add this configuration when you initialize the fluent configuration.

```
Fluently.Configure( Configuration )
                .Mappings( cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AutoMappings.Add( *yourIAutomappingConfiguration* )
                }
```

Comment: Nice work. I guess that code for a collection convention access strategy wasn't too bad after all!

Comment: Yes, it is good, but it is not an answer for the prev question simply because the mapping generated for ISet<T> collection is <bag> instead of <set>. And I still cannot handle it.

Comment: No, no, no. Look again at the convention. Ok, here is a hint; it is operating on an ICollection. Then look at your code again. If you still can't figure it out I will tell you how to generate a set *properly*. HTH

Comment: Well, I tried so many things but I think I miss something fundamental here. If you can help me for this please posti it in the other thread. Thx